# What is the difference between cum, quia and quod in a causal clause?

Tags: classical-latin, conjunction, subordinate-clause

I asked yesterday about [the difference between causal clauses and causal relative clauses](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1261/79), and I was surprised by a comment:
apparently there is a difference between causal *cum* clauses and causal *quia* clauses.
I had not heard of any such difference, so I was left puzzled.
**What is the difference between *cum*, *quia* and *quod* in causal clauses?**

Of course *cum* always requires conjunctive.
With *quia* and *quod* one uses indicative, unless there is some special reason for conjunctive — the cause is an opinion rather than fact or the clause is subordinate to *oratio obliqua*.
My understanding is that *quia* and *quod* are equivalent.

To formulate the question in terms of a concrete example, what is the difference between these sentences?

1. *Amicus meus exire nolebat, cum nimis plueret.*
2. *Amicus meus exire nolebat, quia/quod nimis pluebat.*
3. *Amicus meus exire nolebat, quia/quod nimis plueret.*

In 2 the prohibiting amount of rain is expressed as a fact, in 3 as the friend's opinion.
In 1 this distinction is not made, but otherwise I see no difference between 1 and 2/3.
Is there a difference?
If there is, what is it?

Comment: Just to clarify, my comment wasn't intended to suggest that there was a specific definable difference between *cum*, *quia*, and *quod*, but that they are not identical constructions and therefore the same question you asked about *quippe* can be extended to them. But I'm glad it prompted this question... *Quia* and *quod* are not exactly equivalent in that *quia*, unlike *quod*, is generally used to express a reason that the writer vouches for, as opposed to one ascribed to someone else. (Don't have time to post an answer on that just now but will do so later unless someone beats me to it.)

Comment: @TKR, what I understood from your comment that there is *some* difference, whatever it means. I thought it is worth figuring out separately without comparison to *quippe*. I'd be glad if you could write a full answer when you find the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a partial answer and in need of further substantiation, but I'll post it for what's it's worth.

First, as to the difference between *quod* and *quia*. Though these are often treated as interchangeable, and both can take either the indicative or the subjunctive depending on whether the reason stated is the writer's or is ascribed to someone else, there may be a difference in usage. [Allen and Greenough 540](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-540.html) state:

> > Note 1— *Quod* introduces either a fact or a statement, and accordingly takes either the Indicative or the Subjunctive. *Quia* regularly introduces a fact; hence it rarely takes the Subjunctive. *Quoniam*, inasmuch as, since, when now, now that, has reference to motives, excuses, justifications, and the like and takes the Indicative.

That is, it seems that *quia* and *quoniam* rarely express a reason ascribed to someone else, but normally state a reason that the writer vouches for, while *quod* has no such restriction. That said, it would be good to see other corroboration or a more detailed discussion of this difference. Woodcock's *New Latin Syntax* does not, as far as I can find, mention it; I wouldn't be surprised if the *Oxford Latin Syntax* has something to say about the question (the [table of contents](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y05zCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1397&ots=hQomzTl8ay&dq=oxford%20latin%20syntax%20causal%20clauses&pg=PR16#v=snippet&q=reason%20clauses&f=false) suggests it might), but I don't have access to it at the moment.

As to causal *cum* clauses. My comment which prompted your question wasn't meant to suggest that these are clearly distinct from *quod* or *quia* clauses, only that they shouldn't be assumed *a priori* to be synonymous. "Cause" is [a notoriously non-unitary concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_causes), and true synonymy in language is rare. So-called "causal" *cum* clauses are not really a clearly distinguishable subset of subjunctive *cum* clauses generally, which are normally about describing the circumstances under which something happened; thus Woodcock (p. 192): "Both the causal and concessive (adversative) uses of *cum* are really branches of the generic or descriptive use". The difference between a circumstance with explanatory value and a cause in a stricter or more logical sense is not easy to define, but possibly some such distinction can be drawn between *cum* clauses and *quod/quia* clauses. In terms of English equivalents, a translation like "seeing as" (as opposed to "because") can express the former and is often suitable for *cum* clauses, less so for *quod/quia* clauses.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer that I can give is to adapt the notes I made years ago during instruction in prose composition [which I am doing by inserting comments in square brackets].

ADVERBIAL CLAUSES — CAUSAL

The word *cum* has a whole list of meanings, as conjunction, preposition and adverb. The form *quum* is often found instead of *cum*, and these two are more or less interchangeable as  causal particles — that is, to introduce causal clauses — both being found throughout classical texts. The form seen is often that preferred by the redactor [which may be an obstacle when a *corpus* is consulted to deduce a trend, or a rule based on frequency].

1. [A little contrary to what the question says] The verb following *cum* is *normally in the subjunctive* : but there are a few exceptions —  the indicative can be used when the action of the verb is future or present (e.g. after a few 'verbs of emotion' such as *laudo, doleo, gaudeo*). Note that in adverbial clauses that are NOT causal but temporal, introduced by *cum* = 'when', the indicative is legitimately used in various situations.
2. [For each of the words in question] **English from Latin** is chosen to suit the style of the translator: *since, as, because, seeing that, for the reason that* etc. For **doing into Latin**, on the other hand, *Quia* and *quod* can, like *cum*, be used to translate any of these and, like *cum*, are used with the subjunctive — with indicative ONLY if the reason is given with certainty:

*advenerunt quod cibum susciperent*  **but**  *advenerunt quod cibo egebant*

3. Since causal clauses are syntactically adverbial, the introductory particle can refer to a reason shown in the main clause:

*cibo egebant, idcirco advenerunt quia cibum susciperent*

4.To conclude : When used as logical conjunctions, the differences between *cum,* *quod* and *quia* are minimal. The latter is most often used by the subject of the principal clause in expressing an opinion and is therefore considered rather more emphatic : such usage is not obligatory. The differences hardly show in a good, idiomatic translation from Latin to English : such difficulty as occurs lies in the opposite case, of choosing the most suitable word of Latin to suit an English original. Here, too, teasing out the niceties of difference is a somewhat arid pursuit, for there may be many ways of saying the same thing in English on these occasions, just as in Latin : in the end, it comes down to personal style and preference. In that connection we should remember that not only clarity, but also elegance is desirable in a Latin prose that aspires to high quality.